# Python / Raspberry Pi issue

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

Im trying to make a keyboard with a raspberry pi like [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=91784) but i get this error which i dont know how to solve

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/koden1.py", line 72, in <module>
    key = keypress()
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/koden1.py", line 44, in keypress
    key = pg.key.name(event.key)
AttributeError: event member not defined
```

Source code: https://github.com/anttus/Raspberry-MidiKeyboard/blob/master/midikeyboard.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the `AttributeError` because you are trying to access the `key` attribute of the `event` object which doesn't exists. Lets see what's in the `event` object :

```
>>> dir(event)
[..., 'dict', 'type']
```

The `event.dict` looks good, lets see whats in there with with various `event.type` :

```
<Event(17-VideoExpose {})>
<Event(16-VideoResize {'h': 1, 'size': (1, 1), 'w': 1})>
<Event(1-ActiveEvent {'state': 1, 'gain': 0})>
<Event(4-MouseMotion {'pos': (0, 0), 'rel': (1, 1), 'buttons': (0, 0, 0)})>
<Event(2-KeyDown {'unicode': 'a', 'key': 113, 'mod': 0, 'scancode': 16})>
```

As you can see with "key events" we have what you are looking for,  `event.dict.get('key')`, don't forget to test if the event is a "key event":

```
event = pg.event.wait()
if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN or event.type == pg.KEYUP:
    key = pg.key.name(event.dict.get('key'))
```

Comment: To the original poster: It's also a good idea to handle unexpected events some way. Ignoring them may be the right thing, but that's not certain.